# Run If query multiple times in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have to run an if query multiple times. Now of course I could include the query several times in my code. Is this the clean way? Or should I write this differently?

Here my query

```
if 'xyc_begin' in content and 'xyc_end' in content:
    file.write('xyc available\n')
else:
    print('xyc not available\n')
    file.write('xyc not available\n')
    file.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Now I would have to check for **abc** and **def** (instead of **xyc**) and adjust the line in the file accordingly. How do you program this correctly or do you just do several queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into a list:

```
content = "aaa xyc_begin xyc_end    def_begin def_end   bfasfsdnfl"

look_out_for = ["xyc","abc","def"]

with open("f.txt","w") as f:
    for what in look_out_for:
        if f"{what}_begin" in content and f"{what}_end" in content:
            f.write(f"{what} available\n")
        else:
            f.write(f"{what} NOT available\n") 

print(open("f.txt").read())
```

File content:

```
xyc available
abc NOT available
def available
```